# how to make a property bold while displaying in textarea in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to make some part of text bold while displaying in jquery:

```
$(':checked').each(function() {
    var $textarea = $('textarea');
    $textarea.val($textarea.val() + $(this).prop('name') + ' = ' + this.value + '\n' );
});
```

In the above code, i want to make $(this).prop('name') as bold while displaying it in textarea .

Please give me any suggestion/help

Thank you in advance
Ramsai

Comment: You can't you should use a div with content editable enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text inside a textarea can't be bold, as far as i know, because making text bold requires markup and the textarea is not processed (unless you use a WYSIWYG plugin like Tiny MCE).
You could do something like stackoverflow which has a preview panel where text is previewed with markup

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the formatting of individual characters inside of a `textarea`'s display.

However, you can use a `div` (for example) and set its `contenteditable` attribute, which lets you make certain words bold, for example. This however is much more complicated than a `textarea`.